# Reversing Y axis in MSChart Control

Tags: .net, mschart

I am trying to reverse the Y Axis in MSChart

The scale from left to right would be 5 - 1 So if a bar has a value of 2 it will fill from 5 until 2 on the scale with the score to the right of the filled bar.

[image]
Is this possible with MS Chart?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be adding a second not enabled axis with "is reversed" and displaying the values on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have time to fully test this, but perhaps

```
    objChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
```

... might be a good place to start?

**edit**: I've just tried this actually, and it only flips the entire chart. Probably not what you're after.